# HTML5/CSS issues with border and aside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate this web document, but i'm stuck on a couple of things.  Here is a picture of the web document I am trying to recreate.

[image]

1. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get the border around the main content of the page.  I thought I could just use a divid, call it main, and add a border using the external css sheet, but it doesn't seem to be working.
2. I'm also having problems getting the aside box on the right side of the screen as shown in the image.  I've tried a couple of different things on the internet, but haven't had any success thus far.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is my HTML markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Professional Cycling 2014></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>


<div id="container">
<header>
    <h1>Professional Cycling 2014</h1> 
    <nav id ="navigation" role="navigation">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#Overview">Professional Cycling 2014 - Season Overview</a>&nbsp; </li>

<li><a href="#Races">The Top Races</a>&nbsp; </li> 

<li><a href="#Riders">The Top Riders</a>&nbsp; </li>

<li><a href="#Bikes">Bikes of the Professionals</a>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>



<div id="main" role="main">

<article>

<header>
    <h2>Professional Road Cycling</h2>
</header>


<header>
    <h3>2014 Season Overview</h3> 
</header>

 The professional road season begins in early February in southern Europe and runs through late October with races all over the world. Events range from one-day classics to three-week grand tours. Some of the more famous races are the one-day classics of Paris-Roubaix in northern France, Tour de Flanders in the Belgian heartland, Milan-San Remo along western coast of Italy, and the grand tours of France, Italy, and Spain. Many people who are not cycling fans will have heard of the Tour de France, one of the largest sporting spectacles on earth.
 <br>
 <br>
 Professional cycling is governed by the Union Cyclist Internationale (<a href="http://www.uci.ch">UCI</a>) based in Aigle, Switzerland. 

 </article>

 <article>
 <header>
    <h3>The Top Races</h3> 
</header>


<img alt= "Stage 10 - Tour de France 2013" src="images/image1.jpg" width="75" height="100" />Arguably the biggest race of the year is the Tour de France which is held during July. Some riders specialize their riding style to do well in the grand tours, while other riders will specialize in the one-day classics and shorter stage races. The Tour de France typically has between 20 and 22 stages, usually one stage each day. The winner is determined by the lowest overall cumulative time over all stages. Stages include special stages run individually against the clock called time trials, but most stages are massed-start events with all riders covering the same course together. The Tour de France allows teams of 9 riders and typically between 18 and 22 teams are invited to compete in the event. 

</article>


 <article>
<header>
    <h3>The Top Riders</h3> 
</header>


 <img alt= "Philippe Gilbert former world champion" src="images/image2.jpg" width="75" height="100" />Riders acquire UCI points throughout the year based upon their finishing position in the various races held around the world. The leader on points in any World Tour event wears a special jersey that signifies their leadership position. However, each year, the UCI also hosts the world championship event where the world champion is determined based on the winner of a single day event. For professional riders this event is normally around 150-165 miles long. This past year, Rui Costa of Portugal won the event to be crowned the 2013 World Champion. He will wear a special rainbow jersey until the world championship event next year, where he will attempt to defend his title. 
 <br>
 <br>
 Other top riders in 2013 were Fabian Cancellara of Switzerland, Tom Boonen of Belgium, and Chris Froome of Great Britan. 

 </article>

 </div>


 <div id="sidebar" role="complementary">
  <aside>
 <article>
 <header>
    <h3>Bikes of the professionals</h3> 
</header>

Professional riders use specific bikes for specific events. Time trial bikes being the most specialized with highly aerodynamic builds and disk wheels often used on the rear wheel. Bikes built for climbing are extremely lightweight while bikes built for sprinting or rougher roads are somewhat heavier. A standard professional bike weighs between 14 and 18 pounds. Today most bike frames are made from carbon fiber as are many of the components and wheels. Typical cost is between $6000 and $20,000 USD per bike. Some of the top bike builders are: 

<ul>
<li>Colnago (Italy)</li> 
<li>Ridley (Belgium)</li> 
<li>BMC (Switzerland)</li> 
<li>Trek (USA)</li>  
<li>Bianchi (Italy)</li> 
</ul>
 </article>

 <br></aside>
 </div>

 <footer>
 <small>&copy; Copyright 2014 MJL Productions All Rights Reserved</small>
 </footer>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and my CSS sheet code

```
body {
background-color: #E0E0E0;

}

h1 { 
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-color: red;
border-color: black;
border-width: thin;
border-style: solid;
}

#menu {
list-style-type: none;  
padding: 5;
margin: 15;
}

#menu li 
{    
text-align: center;
background-color: #00CCCC;
border-color: blue;
border-width: thin;
border-style: solid;

}

#main {
border-color: black;
border-width: thick;
position:relative:
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px 10px;
}

#sidebar
{

}
```

Comment: Try `border: 3px solid black;` instead. I don't think you're actually declaring a border, just applying properties to a border that isn't there.

Comment: That's pretty much straight forward stuff. Can you also post the style for the container ? And what do you mean by getting the border around the main content ? what exactly is the main content here ?

Comment: If you just the main body to be bordered, just add the border attribute in your body in the css. Like border: 3px solid black; if you are trying to set the border to some other view in you page, add the border attribute there too. Without the border attribute, you border won't be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, overall this requires too many css changes for an explanation. so i'll simply dumb the css where i've made  changes..

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
body {
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#container{
 height:100%;
}

.....

#menu li {
 display:inline-block; /*Horizontally align menu items*/
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #00CCCC;
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: thin;
 border-style: solid;     
}
#main {
 display:inline-block; /* for horizontally aligning main content and side bar */
 width:50%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 position:relative;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px 10px;
}
#sidebar {
 display:inline-block; /* for horizontally aligning main content and side bar */
 width:40%;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-top:5px;
 border:2px solid black;
}
```

Here's a somewhat similar [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cAEVm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed border-style on this element.

```
#main {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thick;
    position:relative:
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: thick;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

Two things...... you needed to add a border style and you have `:` after position:relative instead of `;`.
Here's what you need: `border-style:solid;` and `position-relative;`

Answer (score -2):

Use `border: 1px solid #000000;`